# getting a strange error when trying to create new ssis project

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, migrate

[image]

this error occurs when i create a new ssis project, i am trying to movie the tables and queries from access to sql server, i tried import/export wizard it didnt work because of data type mismatch, i tried upsizing that only moved the tables. the access queries are too complicated for me to turn it into views any help on migrating access db to sql will help me greatly

Thanks :)

Comment: Error seems pretty straight forward, BIDS is either not installed or the install is messed up. Do you have multiple versions of VisualStudio installed?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli  i have visual studio 2013 and visual studio 2008 installed but the license for 2013 has been expired so right now only 2008 is installed

Answer (score 0):

Run the SQL Server 2008 R2 install and make sure you install BIDS, it's under the Shared Features. If it's already installed try removing it then re-installing and you should be fine.